# Создание 3-х динамических макетов с Custom ViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

Доброго времени суток!
Делаю вёрстку динамического каталога с помощью адаптеров.
Приложение будет отлавливать JSON с данными и впихивать их в 3 фрагмента.
Раньше я всё делал через создание View (А это было давно и скорее всего неправильно)
А сейчас мне надо сделать целых 3 разных макета в одном приложении.
Каким образом можно ПРАВИЛЬНО реализовать 3 различных адаптера?

```
// пункт списка
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.cymbal_item, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

    // заполняем View в пункте списка данными из товаров: название, описание
    // и картинка
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.cymbalName);
    //((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubDescr)).setText(p.cymbalSubName);
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageDrawable(p.cymbalImage);
    Button chooseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseButton);

    chooseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mOnProductSelected.onProductSelected(position);
            //Когда нажали на кнопку , адаптер вернет в функцию onProductSelected
            //которая находится во фрагменте, позицию товара в листе которую выбрали,
            //то есть в фрагменте мы будем знать что выбрали
            //и сможем передать только один продукт в следующий экран
        }

    });

    return view;
}
```

Примеры фрагментов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `RecyclerView` имеет `LayoutManager` и гораздо лучше подходит для вашей задачи. Насчет разного вида и содержимого айтемов смотрите про переопределение метода адаптера `getItemViewType()`/ В общем вам понадобится один адаптер с тремя видами айтемов в `getItemViewType()` и двумя `LayoutManager` - `LinearLayoutManager` для первых двух и ``GridLayoutManager` для третьего.